# How make FTP from remote server1 to remote server2 from client pc

Tags: ftp

I create backup from remote server1 and transfer to remote server2.
i want do this from local computer.
many FTP program like FileZilla transfer files from local to remote or remote to local.
I want locally transfer files from remote server to another remote server from local.

do you know any solution or program?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: windows, i'm search for free solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) and both of the servers in question need to support FXP for this to work.  I don't think the FileZilla client supports FXP so you will need to find a client that does.  There are several out there, FlashFXP is the one I am most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

It's called FXP. On Linux, try `pftpfxp`, `profxp`, ... and FTP Rush, FlashFXP,... on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Windows and want a free option rather than the $30 FlashFXP, you can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_synchronize) to do synchronized real-time backups.

Comment: WinSCP can't do FXP in any way